# How to run SDE view commands in Oracle DB?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase

I would like to create SDE view to compare two tables in my oracle spatial database. 
I already prepared the view commands. But I dont know where and how to run this?
I unable to run this commands in Toad SQL editor like other sql statements.

Please help me if any one have idea.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com seems a more appropriate place for this question.

Comment: Unless you are talking about a spatial view, this is off-topic.

Comment: Yes. I need to to create spatial view. But I dont know Where exactly I have run those commands.

Comment: Command mode?  or SQL editor?

Comment: A little basic research would go along ways: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Creating_a_spatial_view_in_Oracle_using_SQL/002n000000t3000000/ http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002n000000t1000000

Comment: Yes. I already prepared the commands in notepad, but where I have to execute these sde view commands?

Comment: It would help if you posted said commands.

Comment: sdetable -o create_view -T....

Comment: I found that I can run these commands in DOS prompt only